# How to get value to be from 0 to 1?

Tags: c#

I tried to look for an answer for this problem but I guess nobody has needed something like this or it's something super simple that I just can't get my head around. So:

I have a value that changes from 45 to 20.

I'd need a value that goes from 0 to 1 in same time as 45 goes to 20. I know that 45 - 20 = 25 and that would be my 100% and hence the number 1.

I'd implement this in Lerp value like this:

```
public float minHeight = 10.0f;
public float maxHeight = 30.0f;
public float convertedValue;
```

convertedValue = ??? (Something like 45 - 20 = 25 = 100%) * 0.01;

```
newValue = Mathf.Lerp(minHeight, maxHeight, convertedValue);
```

Hopefully someone can help me. Im fairly new to coding and I was just wondering if this is possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You question is confusing, you are talking of 45 and 20 but showing 10 and 30.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just meant that value that controls my lerp is 45 - 20 and 10 and 30 are just parts of it. I'll clean it up soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the calculation matching your explanation would be

```
newValue = (convertedValue - minHeight) / (maxHeight - minHeight);
```

i.e. `newValue = 0` @ `minHeight`, and 1 @ `maxHeight`

**Edit**

I've never seen Lerp before, but apparantly it is simple linear interpolation.

However, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.lerp.aspx)

Lerp is defined as

```
value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount
```

i.e. in your example `convertedValue` should be the fraction, and the answer is the interpolated result, meaning that your question / my (and Esailja's) interpretation thereof is inverted :)

i.e.

```
Mathf.Lerp(10.0, 30.0, 0.5) = 20.0
```

whereas

```
InvertedLerp(10.0, 30.0, 20) = 0.5 // My / Esailja's calc
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and nice solution! And thanks for all that participated in cleaning this up. Sorry about messy question.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize your [`Mathf.Lerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) as part of the `Unity3D` APIs.  A function there already exists to do what you're trying to do: [`Mathf.InverseLerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html).  You should use this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public float minHeight = 10.0f;
public float maxHeight = 30.0f;

float curHeight = 25.0f;

float newValue = ( curHeight - minHeight ) / ( maxHeight - minHeight );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minvalue=20
maxvalue=45
result=(aktvalue-minvalue)/(maxvalue-minvalue)
```

something like this?

Answer (score 0):

How about a property?

```
public int neededvalue
{
    get
    {
        if (value == 45)
            return 1;
        else if (value == 20)
            return 0
        else
            throw new Exception("wrong input");
    }
}

public float neededvaluealternative
{
    get
    {
        return (value - 20) / (45 - 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public float AnswerMureahkosQuestion(float input)
{
   const float minValue = 20;
   const float maxValue = 45;
   float range = maxValue - minValue;

   // nominalise to 1
   // NOTE: you don't actually need the *1 but it reads better
   float answer = (input+0.00001/*prevents divbyzero errors*/) / range * 1; 

   // invert so 45 is 0 and 20 is 1
   answer =  1 - answer;
   return answer;
}
```